# Split Dartboard into Polygons

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I'm looking for a way to split a dartboard image into polygons so that given an x,y coordinate I can find out which zone the dart fell within. I have found a working python script to detect if the coordinate falls within a polygon (stored as a list of x,y pairs), but I am lost as to how to generate the polygons as a list of points. I'm open to creating the "shape map" if that's the correct term, in whatever way necessary to get it done, I just don't know the correct technology or method to do this.

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue is. Normally, x and y coordinates (of the dart)  will be given relative to the top-left corner of the image so you will need to add the radius of the dartboard to each to get your coordinates relative to the centre of the dartboard.

There are 20 segments on a dartboard, so each segment will subtend 360/20 or 18 degrees around the centre. You can get the angle from the vertical using `tan inverse x/y` and test which segment, and therefore, which number that corresponds to.

The distance from the centre will be `sqrt(x^2 + y^2)` and you can test if that is within the segment corresponding to a treble or a double.

Comment: The problem is I don't think like a computer scientist or mathmetician, but I think you've given me everything I need to muddle through it. Thanks Mark!